# What the document.getElementsByTagNameNS command does

Tags: javascript, dom

What the document.getElementsByTagNameNS does and does it have html5 support

Comment: Try [a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mdn+getelementsbytagnamens&t=he&ia=about) before you try Stackoverflow

Comment: I heard that google knows, ask him!

Comment: This is not a question for stackoverflow. Please read about it online.

Answer (score 3):

Doc here: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS

Retrieves all dom elements by tagname and namespace.

Sample with xhtml namespace:

```
var cells = table.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "td");
```

same as getElementsByTagName, where default namespace is (x)html

```
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

you can use getElementsByTagNameNS to retrive dom elements with different namespace, like svg or mathml.

svg sample:

```
 var paths = canvas.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
```